# How to "reset" style in view page, set in css file

Tags: html, css

For a `li` element I have specified the width in a stylesheet:

```
width: 100px;
```

Now for one specific `li` instance in a view, I would like this width to not apply and instead I would like a `max-width: 200px;`. So I add to a view file in Rails:

```
<li style="max-width:200px">
```

However, this of course does not overwrite `width` so that still a width of 100px applies.
 *Is there a way to remove the width for just this one element, without making changes nor adjustments to the css file?* So in the view file something like `width: unspecified`.

Comment: The initial value of width is auto, so can't you simply set the width to auto? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width

Comment: use [initial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value) value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value of width is Auto, in CSS.

so:

```
<li style="width:auto; max-width:200px">
```

Comment: Judging by their history I'm sure the OP knows very well how to mark answers as accepted. They just can't do it for another 5 minutes. Be patient.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock for the tip :) i will check OP history before urging him in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can "reset" the attribute setting it to it's initial value, for [width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) the initial value is auto.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know what the default for an attribute is, just use the `initial` keyword.

```
<li style="width:initial; max-width:200px">
```

That resets any attribute that you apply it to.

Here's for a more detailed description of [initial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial).

Comment: initial isn't very well supported at the moment - even if you're only interested in the latest versions of major browsers, both IE and Presto-based Opera don't support it, and neither of these are going to be updated with support for initial anytime soon (they'll be replaced with Edge and Blink Opera though).

Answer (score 0):

you can use a class or id for this specific li, suppose

```
<li class = "specifieclass">test</li>
```

then add css for this class

```
.specifieclass
 {
     width:auto;
     max-width:200px;
  }
```

you can use more css for this class
 or normally use

```
<li style="max-width:200px;width:auto; ">
```